# Laravel stripe integration

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I setup future payment in my laravel app with stripe. However, after following stripe integration from stripe official doc I encountered this error response.

[image]

**Here's my script:**

```
<script>
    var stripeSetupIntent = function (stripe, setupIntent) {
        const email      = document.getElementById("stripe-email").value;

        stripe.confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret,
            {
                payment_method: {
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: {
                        name: email,
                    },
                },
            }
        ).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                // Display error.message in your UI.
                console.log('Error: ', result.error)


                // var displayError = document.getElementById("card-errors");
                // displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                console.log('Sucess')
                // The setup has succeeded. Display a success message.
            }
        });
    };

    var getSetupIntent = function(stripe) {

        axios.post('/api/createcustomerinstripe').then(function (response) {

            console.log('getSetupIntent: ', response.data.setupIntent)

            stripeSetupIntent(stripe, response.data.setupIntent)
        })
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        let stripe = null;

        //get stripe public key
        axios.get('/api/stripe-key').then(function (response) {
            
            stripe           = Stripe(response.data.publicKey);
            const elements   = stripe.elements();
            const card       = elements.create('card');

            card.mount('#card-element');
        })

        var button = document.getElementById("savecard");

        button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            // changeLoadingState(true);
            getSetupIntent(stripe)
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Backend code:**
**Controller:**

```
public function getStripeKey()
{
    $publicKey = env('STRIPE_KEY');

    $data = [
        'message'   => 'Stripe key successfully retrieved.',
        'publicKey' => $publicKey
    ];

    return response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
public function CreateCustomerInStripe()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    $customer = Customer::create([
        'email' => auth()->user()->email
    ]);

    $setupIntent = SetupIntent::create([
        'customer' => $customer->id
    ]);

    $data = [
        'message' => 'A new SetupIntent was created.',
        'setupIntent' => $setupIntent
    ];

    return response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

**Backend code web:**

```
Route::get('stripe-key', 'api\StripePaymentController@getStripeKey')->name('stripe.key');
Route::post('createcustomerinstripe', 'api\StripePaymentController@CreateCustomerInStripe')->name('createcustomerinstripe');
```

I use the stripe documentation here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-test-integration

stripe version:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

laravel version:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing
```

Comment: I suspect `return response()->json($data, 200, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` is the culprit, but I'm not entirely sure why - possibly something pretty-print related.  Can you try just sending back the data you receive from Stripe as-is?

Comment: I was able to fixed it myself. I put the wrong setup my bad. But thanks for your response anyway.